# C++ Standalone Media Player using integrated library instead of installed codecs

Tags: c++, media-player, directshow, codec

I have written C++ code to decode video files using installed codecs with directshow.
I would like to build a standalone media player that will be limited to a predefined library such as FFMPEG.

What options do I have for this sort of functionality?

Comment: Player is to be still DirectShow based, or you don't care - it can be anything, just self-contained?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be directshow based. Something like VLC

Comment: Does anyone know where I might find more information on this subject?

Comment: You write "like VLC" and VLC is open source, so you can just look up its internals...